# How do I decode escaped unicode javascript code in Python?

Tags: javascript, python, unicode

I have this string:

```
V posledn\u00edch m\u011bs\u00edc\u00edch se bezpe\u010dnostn\u00ed situace v Libyi zna\u010dn\u011b zhor\u0161ila, o \u010dem\u017e sv\u011bd\u010d\u00ed i ned\u00e1vn\u00e9 n\u00e1hl\u00e9 opu\u0161t\u011bn\u00ed zem\u011b nejen \u010desk\u00fdmi diplomaty. Libyi hroz\u00ed nekontrolovan\u00fd rozpad a nekone\u010d
```

Which should read "V posledních měsících se ..."
so \u00ed is í and \u011b is ě.

Any idea how to decode this in Python? It is a javascript code I am parsing in python. I could write my own ad-hoc solution as there are not that many characters that are escaped (there are only twelve or so accented characters in Czech), but that seems ugly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Decode it using the `'unicode-escape'` codec.  If `x` is your string, `x.decode('unicode-escape')`.

Comment: `'\u2019'.decode('unicode-escape')` gives me `u'\u2019'` (Python 2.7.17)

Comment: My bad, `r'\u2019'.decode('unicode-escape')` gives `u'\u2019'`, which printed gives `’` as expected

Comment: `.encode().decode('unicode-escape')` If you are dealing with a string in python that is already encoded like this.

Answer (score 1):

If it is Javascript code, then perhaps it's actually JSON, and you can use `json.loads` to decode it.

Comment: That does not seem to work straigth away (it says it is no json) and the answer by BrenBarn actually works great, thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, was solved by:

`unicodedata.normalize('NFD', my_string.decode('unicode-escape')).encode('ascii','ignore')`