# Converting a scraped unicode string into regular Python strings

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding

this issue has been driving me crazy. I am scraping a webpage using the requests module. The string I get in return is this:

```
x = "\nM\\u00fcnster - Melbourne - New York\n\\ud83d\\udc7b kaptenandson"
```

I can't seem to be able to get it to output normally, neither on terminal, nor anywhere else (output files, etc.). The text contains an umlaut and two emojis but I am just not able to work with it – drives me crazy.

Further, I have read through the resources on unicode but they haven't been of any help in this case. Are there any other unicode / encoding tutorials in Python I can read?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! The string I got was javascript escaped. Pointing to the right answer here:

[How do I decode escaped unicode javascript code in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25457598/how-do-i-decode-escaped-unicode-javascript-code-in-python)

Comment: Link-only answer are discouraged.  I closed as a duplicate instead.

Comment: Thanks @MarkTolonen!